# Permission for publish stream is not being done properly

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have made an application that needs me to publish an audio file to facebook, I can successfully publish that but the problem is, when I login to facebook through my application it shows a permission dialog, every thing file till here, but when I tap the "Allow" button on the publish dialog it shows the error message that user hasn't authorized you publishing permission(even I clicked Allow).
But for the second time when I log in to facebook, it doesn't show me the permission dialog and the audio file get successfully published.

I can't find where the problem is.
Please help me!!

Thanx...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the session problem there. now it has been resolved.